# Usage of multiple "als" in a German sentence

Tags: grammar

I have a German sentence. The whole sentence is:

> 'Nach seiner Inhaftierung beginnt er, seinen Plan in die Tat umzusetzen, was sich jedoch als schwieriger herausstellt als urspünglich geplant'.

I believe that 'was' is a relative pronoun translating to English 'which'.

Whats the purpose and meaning of using 'als ... als' twice in this sentence?

Comment: As you can see from Hubert Schölnast's answer, the two "als" don't belong together but are a part of different constructions: "sich *als* etwas herausstellen" = "to shape up *as* sth." - "schwieriger *als*" = "more difficult *than*"

Comment: If you want to avoid the second *als*, you could use the synonymous expression *sich gestalten*: "*…, was sich jedoch schwieriger gestaltet als ursprünglich geplant*". This would sound slightly better, but it's also absolutely okay to leave the sentence as it is.

Answer (score 2):

"Als" has three different functions:

- introduce a side clause about a past event
- coordinate comparisons that look at "inequality"
- "assign" roles

Here's an example for each:

> Als ich Kind war,...
>   When I was a kid...
>
> Sie ist schlauer als ich.
>   She is smarter than me/I.
>
> Als Präsident Koch ist er gut, als Kellner nicht.
>   He's good as a cook but not as a waiter. (semi-literal)

The first "als" in your sentence, though not immediately obvious, is assigning a role. The second one is a classical comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Original German sentence:

> Nach seiner Inhaftierung beginnt er, seinen Plan in die Tat umzusetzen, was sich jedoch als schwieriger herausstellt als urspünglich geplant.

English translation:

> After his arrest he begins to implement his plan, which turns out to be harder than planed originally.

this might help:

> etwas stellt sich **als** etwas (anderes) heraus = something turn out to be something (different)
>   anders sein **als** geplant = to be different than planned

Answer (score -3):

I'm from Germany. In this sentence, you can't use "als" twice. 
It has to be

> Nach seiner Inhaftierung beginnt er, seinen Plan in die Tat umzusetzen, was sich jedoch schwieriger herausstellt als ursprünglich geplant.

Comment: I disagree. I would correct this sentence to »... was sich jedoch **als** schwieriger herausstellt als ursprünglich geplant.«

Comment: Duplicate 'als' like this is syntactically 100% fine. Euphony, however, considers the effect unharmonious and disprefers it. Whether the resulting structure is 'right' or 'wrong' therefore depends on which principle is more important. In a legal document, syntax is way more important. In a poem, euphony usually is more important.